# How to access a column in an another table using EF Core while there is relationship between those tables

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF core to establish a connection with the database. My database is SQLite.
My properties are:
**Topic:**

```
public class Topic
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<SubTopic> SubTopics { get; set; }
    }
```

**SubTopic:**

```
public class SubTopic
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string SubTopicname { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string ShortDiscription { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Discription { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Reference { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Name")]
        public virtual Topic Topic { get; set; }

    }
```

I want to write a query to find a row in the `SubTopic` table that the corresponding topic name in the `Topics` table is `Technology`.
I tried this:
`var subTopic = await _myContext.SubTopic.Include(x => x.Topic.Name == "Technology").FirstAsync()`;

But it does not work. What is the correct way to write such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Include` should have an expression pointing to the navigation property.

```
var subTopic = await _myContext.SubTopic
    .Include(st => st.Topic)
    .Where(x => x.Topic.Name == "Technology")
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Since .NET 5, EF Core supports filtered includes too:

```
var subTopic = await _myContext.SubTopic
    .Include(st => st.Topic
        .Where(t => t.Name == "Technology")
    )
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But in your case you probably shouldn't even need to include the navigation property:

```
var subTopic = await _myContext.SubTopic
    //.Include(st => st.Topic)
    .Where(st => st.Topic.Name == "Technology")
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Although I read that this could slow down performance on large datasets

Comment: *Although I read that this could slow down performance on large datasets* ? What do you mean? `Include` slowdowns if it is not needed- yes, without `Include` everything should be faster.